# Finding duplicate values in array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to find the duplicate values in an array. When a number is duplicated once like `(25,25)` program correctly prints 25 once but when a number duplicated twice like `(12,12,12)` program prints 12 three times while it should print it once.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
    int numbers[15]={1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9},i,j;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<14;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i]==numbers[j+1])
            {
                printf("Number %d has duplicate values\n",numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number 1 has duplicate values
Number 2 has duplicate values
Number 2 has duplicate values
Number 2 has duplicate values
Number 6 has duplicate values
Number 7 has duplicate values
Number 7 has duplicate values
Number 7 has duplicate values
```

The arrays cannot be assumed to be ordered so the program should work even with `{1,2,1,2,3,4,2,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9}`.

Comment: When you find the duplicate, you need to search from the beginning of the array again to see if there was a duplicate already found, if there is, don't print it the second time, cause it was printed the first time.

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: You can use index table (depending on your problem). In index table, whenever you find value, you bump up the value at given index. This way, you can traverse table once for finding values and index table another one time for printing doubles.

Comment: Basically: if equal, set flag else clear flag. If flag set, print & clear flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem at hand is essentially simple. There is no need for any complicated code fragments. All it takes is just a little modification to the limits of the `for` loops and how you check for duplicates.

**The solution:**

Just introduce another array which is going to store the elements which are repeated in the array. Start filling this array from the 0th index as and when you find a NEWLY REPEATED element. This can easily be done iterating through this new array and checking if the currently encountered repeated element is already present or not. If it is not present there, then insert into the new array, which in the code I have given below is `arr2[]`.

Hence whatever elements will be held by this new array are the unique repeated elements. I have attached the code and corresponding output below.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int numbers[15] = {1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9}, i, j;
    int arr2[15], k = 0, k1 = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
       {
           flag = 0;
           if(i != j && numbers[i] == numbers[j])
           {
               for(k1 = 0; k1 < k; k1++)
                   if(arr2[k1] == numbers[j])
                     flag = 1;
               if(flag != 1)
                   arr2[k++] = numbers[j];
           }
       }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
      printf("Number %d has duplicate values\n",arr2[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
> Number 1 has duplicate values
> Number 2 has duplicate values
> Number 6 has duplicate values
> Number 7 has duplicate values
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A solution which doesn't introduce additional memory requirements and finds unique duplicates in a worst case of O(N²):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// macro that evaluates to the number of elements in an array:
#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(arr) sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)

// contains() returns true if [values, values + size) contains value
bool contains(int *values, size_t size, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if (values[i] == value)
            return true;
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZEOF_ARRAY(numbers) - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (contains(numbers, i, numbers[i])) // if we already encountered numbers[i]
            continue;                         // it was already identified as dup.

        if(contains(numbers + i + 1, SIZEOF_ARRAY(numbers) - i , numbers[i]))
            printf("Number %d has duplicate values\n", numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Number 1 has duplicate values
Number 2 has duplicate values
Number 6 has duplicate values
Number 7 has duplicate values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with low numbers, you can always go via index table

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int index[256] = {0};
  int table[15] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {
    index[table[i]] ++;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    index[i] > 1 ? printf("%d\n",i) : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is more commonly called a [frequency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

In your example consider the indexes of the 7: they are 10, 11, 12.

The first print happens when `i=10` and `j=10` because your are indexing `numbers[10]` and `numbers[11]`.

At the next iteration of the inner loop you have `i=10` and `j=11` and the condition is verified again by the elements `numbers[10]` and `numbers[12]`.

Finally the third condition happens when `i=11` and `j=11` because you are referring to `numbers[11]` and `numbers[12]`.

All this becomes clear if you print your indexes when the condition happens. For example you can substitute your `printf` with this:

```
printf("Number %d has duplicate values with indexes i=%d, j=%d\n",numbers[i], i,j);
```

which prints:

```
Number 1 has duplicate values with indexes i=0, j=0
Number 2 has duplicate values with indexes i=2, j=2
Number 2 has duplicate values with indexes i=2, j=3
Number 2 has duplicate values with indexes i=3, j=3
Number 6 has duplicate values with indexes i=8, j=8
Number 7 has duplicate values with indexes i=10, j=10
Number 7 has duplicate values with indexes i=10, j=11
Number 7 has duplicate values with indexes i=11, j=11
```

If your values are ordered you can do something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
    int numbers[15]={1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9},i,j;
    int last_dup = -1;

    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<14;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i]==numbers[j] && numbers[i]!=last_dup)
            {
                printf("Number %d has duplicate values with indexes i=%d, j=%d\n",numbers[i], i,j);
                last_dup = numbers[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I initialized to `-1` assuming your numbers are all positive. If not you can save the index of the last duplicate and reference using in the check `numbers[last_dup_idx]` (be careful to initialize the value properly and not go out the length of the array). I also added a `break`: since you already found a duplicate there is no need to continue the second loop.

If your array is not ordered, you can create an additional array saving the duplicates elements every time you find one and then iterate through this array to check.

**FOR NOT ORDERED ARRAYS**

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
    int numbers[15]={1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9},i,j;
    int dups [7];//at most 15/2 duplicates
    char dup_idx=0;
    char found_new_duplicate; //initialized later
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<14;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i]==numbers[j])
            {
                found_new_duplicate = 1;

                //check in the duplicates array
                for (int kk=0; kk<=dup_idx; kk++)
                {
                    if (dups[kk]==numbers[i] && !(i==0 && j==1))
                    {
                        found_new_duplicate = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found_new_duplicate)
                {
                    dups[dup_idx] = numbers[i]; //insert the new duplicate in the duplicates array
                    printf("Number %d has duplicate values with indexes i=%d, j=%d\n",numbers[i], i,j);
                    printf("New duplicate %d\n", dups[dup_idx]);
                    dup_idx++;//increase the index
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int kk=0; kk< dup_idx; kk++)
        printf("%d\n", dups[kk]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but i made a mistake in the question. I gave the numbers in order. I wanted an answer for both ways. BTW thank you

Comment: I added a part of code for non ordered arrays: see if you can understand it.